# How to remove a line from quick book invoice by using php quickbooks api

Tags: php, quickbooks

we are using php quickbooks api.

we want to delete a line from quickbooks invoice.
we are using below code to delete a line from invoice, but it did not worked and it did not shows any error.

```
$Qbinvoice = $InvoiceService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE Id = '$quickBookInvoiceId' ");
$QBSubInvoices = $Qbinvoice[0];
$lines = $QBSubInvoices->getLine();
$count = $QBSubInvoices->countLine();

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $QBSubInvoices->unsetLine($lines->$i);
}
```

Please help me any one, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you actually try to update the invoice? Where is your code for updating the invoice?

Comment: In Quick book Invoice we had 3 lines, on update quick book invoice  we need to delete one line,

Comment: OK, so what code have you used to try to do that?